# How to inject gRPC client to the singleton service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, grpc-c#

`Grpc.Net.ClientFactory` package provides gRPC integration with the IHttpClientFactory and it comes with the convinient extension method used to register gRPC clients: `IServiceCollection.AddGrpcClient<TClient>()`.

The problem is that this method registers `TClient` with the transient lifetime, which is, in turn, means that it's imposible to inject it into the singleton service. And looks like there is no possibility to configure it somehow (at least the AddGrpcClient source code has nothing on that).

So the question is: how to correclty inject the gRPC client to the singleton service and benefit from the IHttpClientFactory integration at the same time? Should I inject some client factory instead?

Answer (score 1):

How about using named Grpc client to register the client, using like this.

```
// Register on the Startup.cs
services
    .AddGrpcClient<Catalog.CatalogClient>("Catalog", o =>
    {
        o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
    });

// Create your service
public class OrderingService : IOrderingService
{
    private readonly Catalog.CatalogClient _client;

    public OrderingService(GrpcClientFactory grpcClientFactory)
    {
        _client = grpcClientFactory.CreateClient<Catalog.CatalogClient>("Catalog");
    }
}

// Register the service as singleton at Startup.cs
service.AddSingleton<IOrderingService, OrderingService>();

// now _client instance is persist as long as you doesn't do anything weird with it
```

Comment: Thanks, sure it will work, but injection of the non-generic GrpcClientFactory smells a bit - it brings some ambiguity to the constructor of the consuming service and makes unclear what exact gRPC service will be used inside this service. Of course we can fix it by creating custom generic GrpcClientFactory, but the question was about the convinient builtin approach (if it exists or not).

Comment: I afraid there's no builtin solution to that, as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-grpc-services-with-a-net-client) has already point-out the grpc client was create concreted. And beside, you don't want to hold the grpc client long live, due to it's make use of HttpClient behind the screen, which is not getting update to [DNS change](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18348). Take a consider of scope approach instead @rtf_leg
And i forget that on the above answer... my bad :D

Answer (score 0):

The grpc client might be a new instance each time (transient), but the underlying `HttpClientMessageHandler` ["is managed"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

I see no problems injecting a transient instance into a singleton service.